# POD don't have access to internet with minikube

Tags: python, kubernetes, slack, minikube

I have a python application using Slack API though slackclient lib. I works fine on a docker image. But then I created a deployment to Kubernetes and stated the application on Minikube. It just can't connect to the internet to get the Slack messages.

I am not using any K8S Services since I don't need to expose anything from my service, just call the Slack service already exposed on the internet.

What I need to do to enable that connection?

Update 1 (exception given):

```
10/03/2019 19:44:50 Starting new HTTPS connection (1): slack.com:443
10/03/2019 19:44:51 https://slack.com:443 "POST /api/rtm.start HTTP/1.1" 200 8581
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 162, in <module>
    request, channel, ts, user = parse_slack_output(slack_client.rtm_read())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slackclient/client.py", line 128, in rtm_read
    json_data = self.server.websocket_safe_read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slackclient/server.py", line 186, in websocket_safe_read
    data += "{0}\n".format(self.websocket.recv())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 313, in recv
    opcode, data = self.recv_data()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 330, in recv_data
    opcode, frame = self.recv_data_frame(control_frame)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 343, in recv_data_frame
    frame = self.recv_frame()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 377, in recv_frame
    return self.frame_buffer.recv_frame()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_abnf.py", line 361, in recv_frame
    self.recv_header()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_abnf.py", line 309, in recv_header
    header = self.recv_strict(2)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_abnf.py", line 396, in recv_strict
    bytes_ = self.recv(min(16384, shortage))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 452, in _recv
    return recv(self.sock, bufsize)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_socket.py", line 112, in recv
    "Connection is already closed.")
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketConnectionClosedException: Connection is already closed.
```

There is a problem when calling the function slack_client.rtm_read() in app.py

```
SLACK_BOT_TOKEN = environ.get('SLACK_BOT_TOKEN')
slack_client = SlackClient(SLACK_BOT_TOKEN)

def parse_slack_output(event_list):
    """
        The Slack Real Time Messaging API is an events firehose.
        this parsing function returns None unless a message is
        directed at the Bot, based on its ID.
    """
    if len(event_list) > 0:
        for event in event_list:
            if is_for_me(event):
                return event['text'], \
                       event['channel'], \
                       event['ts'], \
                       event['user']
    return None, None, None, None
if __name__ == '__main__':
    READ_WEBSOCKET_DELAY = 1 # 1 second delay between reading from firehose
    if slack_client.rtm_connect():
        while True:
            request, channel, ts, user = parse_slack_output(slack_client.rtm_read())
```

Comment: Can you reach anything on the internet from your pod? If so, then check if you can call the normal Slack API (not the websocket). Remember that Minikube runs a VM, so it's behind another NAT which may cause some networking issues. You can also get into the raw VM by running `minikube ssh`.

Comment: Try to run a generic container and see if it has network connectivity: kubectl run busybox --image=busybox --rm -ti --restart=Never --command -- ping -c 5 google-public-dns-a.google.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an opensource project with all adjustments for a working Slack bot in Minikube using slackclient:
https://github.com/staticdev/k8s-python-slackbot

Answer (score 0):

What is the error or exception you are getting while requesting that API ?
Is it a DNS resolution issue ?

If it is a DNS resolution issue.
Then check if KubeDNS or CoreDNS is running on your kubernetes cluster.
If specified above is running then try pinging the host from your pod.

Edit 1:

Looks like the socket connection is getting closed while reading from the server.
Try passing auto_reconnect argument while calling rtm_connect function.

```
slack_client.rtm_connect(auto_reconnect = True)
```

Comment: I've updated the question with the exception and code related. I did not have indications that it is a DNS resolution issue.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Looks like socket connection is getting closed and your code is trying to read on a closed connection.

Comment: I've been using this application on docker for more than a year. It works perfectly and stable on the same machine. The problem started as I began using minikube, so there is some network issue with minikube configuration.

Comment: I believe socket connection is getting closed. Might be due to default minikube config or something else. Can you check the time difference between the first rtm_connect and this exception being raised ? and is the difference same every time.

Comment: It gives the exception almost imediately. I also tried enabling ingress with "minikube addons enable ingress", but it made no difference =/